# How to create a Python class that is a subclass of another class, but fails issubclass and/or isinstance tests?

Tags: python

I know this is probably bad design, but I've run into a case where I need to create a subclass `Derived` of a class `Base` on-the-fly, and make instances of `Derived` fail the `issubclass(Derived, Base)` or `isinstance(derived_obj, Base)` checks (i.e. return `False`).

I've tried a number of approaches, but none succeeded:

- Creating a property named `__class__` in `Derived` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958013/4909228). This can only be used to make the checks return `True`.
- Overriding the `__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__` methods of `Base`. This doesn't work because CPython only calls these methods when conventional checks return `False`.
- Assigning the `__class__` attribute during `__init__`. This is no longer allowed in Python 3.6+.
- Making `Derived` subclass `object` and assigning all its attributes and methods (including special methods) to that of `Base`. This doesn't work because certain methods (e.g. `__init__`) cannot be called on an instance that is not a subclass of `Base`.

Can this possibly be done in Python? The approach could be interpreter specific (code is only run in CPython), and only needs to target Python versions 3.6+.

---

To illustrate a potential usage of this requirement, consider the following function:

```
def map_structure(fn, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [map_structure(fn, x) for x in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: map_structure(fn, v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    # check whether `obj` is some other collection type
    ...
    # `obj` must be a singleton object, apply `fn` on it
    return fn(obj)
```

This method generalizes `map` to work on arbitrarily nested structures. However, in some cases we don't want to traverse a certain nested structure, for instance:

```
# `struct` is user-provided structure, we create a list for each element
struct_list = map_structure(lambda x: [x], struct)
# somehow add stuff into the lists
...
# now we want to know how many elements are in each list, so we want to
# prevent `map_structure` from traversing the inner-most lists
struct_len = map_structure(len, struct_list)
```

If the said functionality can be implemented, then the above could be changed to:

```
pseudo_list = create_fake_subclass(list)
struct_list = map_structure(lambda x: pseudo_list([x]), struct)
# ... and the rest of code should work
```

Comment: Yes, that's terrible design. You probably should use composition in some way.

Comment: What you're asking for is implementation inheritance without the interface inheritance (or at least, the closest approximation Python has to interface inheritance). And that's a perfect use case for composition. If your object shouldn't be iterated like a `list`, then it isn't a `list`. Plain and simple. To make it a list violates duck typing, Liskov substitution, and probably other principles.

Comment: Have you tried adding a metaclass to the base implementing `__instancecheck__`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Overriding the `__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__` methods of `Base`. This doesn't work because CPython only calls these methods when conventional checks return `False`.

This statement is a misconception. These hooks are to be defined on the *metaclass*, not on a base class ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks)).

```
>>> class Meta(type): 
...     def __instancecheck__(self, instance): 
...         print("instancecheck", self, instance) 
...         return False 
...     def __subclasscheck__(self, subclass): 
...         print("subclasscheck", self, subclass) 
...         return False 
...
>>> class Base(metaclass=Meta):
...     pass
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     pass
...
>>> obj = Derived()
>>> isinstance(obj, Base)
instancecheck <class '__main__.Base'> <__main__.Derived object at 0xcafef00d>
False
>>> issubclass(Derived, Base)
subclasscheck <class '__main__.Base'> <class '__main__.Derived'>
False
```

Be aware of the CPython performance optimizations which prevent custom instance check hooks from being called in some special cases (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47740953/674039) for details). In particular, you may not strong-arm the return value of `isinstance(obj, Derived)` because of a [CPython fast path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/abstract.c#L2377-L2379) when there was an exact match.

As a final note, I agree with the commenters that it's not sounding like a very promising design. It seems like you should consider using composition over inheritance in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! One more question: is it possible to dynamically add a metaclass to an existing class (including built-in classes)?

Comment: That's not possible (and it doesn't make a lot of sense to modify the metaclass if the class is already created, since the main responsibility of the metaclass is customizing class creation). For user-defined types, you can possibly dynamically monkeypatch the instance check and subclass check *methods* themselves, but you certainly can not do this on built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out: use composition.

Make a class that is not recursively mapped:

```
class NotMapped:
    pass
```

Then use composition and derive your classes from it:

```
class Derived(NotMapped):
    pass
```

Then add a case at the beginning of your function:

```
def map_structure(fn, obj):

    if isinstance(obj, NotMapped):
        return obj
    # special-case container types etc.
    ...
    return fn(obj)
```

Use this together with multiple inheritance as a sort of mixin. Create convenience ctors for container types, so NotMapped([1, 2, 3]) works as expected.